# Code not working

Tags: javascript

```
var weight = parseInt(prompt("What is your weight?"));
var height = parseInt(prompt("What is your height?"));
var bmi;  
bmi= weight/ height; 
var bmiResult = bmi.toFixed(2); 
alert("your weight is" + bmiResult); 

if (bmiResult>=30) {     
  alert("obese");
}
else if (bmiResult>25 || bmi<30) {     
  alert('overweight');
}
else if (bmiResult>18.5 || bmi<=25) {     
  alert('normal');
}
else if (bmiResult>=16 || <=18.5) {     
  alert('underweight');
}
else (bmiResult<16) {     
  alert('very underweight');
}
```

This code doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why... I'm trying to get the if/else statements to work based on the user input for their weight / height. Can anyone explain why its not working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: you should choose between bmi and bmiResult, too

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put the **variable** before the operator `<=`

Here:

```
bmi= weight/ height; 

var bmiResult = bmi.toFixed(2); 

alert("your weight is" + bmiResult); 

if (bmiResult>=30) {     
alert("obese");
}

else if (bmiResult>25 || bmi<30)
{     alert('overweight');
}

else if (bmiResult>18.5 || bmi<=25)
{     alert('normal');
}

else if (bmiResult>=16 || bmiResult<=18.5)    // <== their it is
{     alert('underweight');
}

else (bmiResult<16)
{     alert('very underweight');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback!! i have fixed that and updated it slightly

Comment: var weight = parseInt(prompt("What is your weight?"));
var height = parseInt(prompt("What is your height?"));
var bmi;

bmi= weight/ height;

var bmiResult = bmi.toFixed(2);

alert("your weight is" + bmiResult);

if (bmiResult>=30) {
    alert("obese");
}
else if (bmiResult>25 && bmiResult<30) {
    alert('overweight');
}
else if (bmiResult>18.5 && bmiResult<=25) {
    alert('normal');
}
else if (bmiResult>=16 && bmiResult<=18.5) {
    alert('underweight');
}
else (bmiResult<16) {
    alert('very underweight');
}

Comment: I have fixed it now.

Comment: var weight = parseInt(prompt("What is your weight?"));
var height = parseInt(prompt("What is your height?"));
var bmi;
bmi = weight / height;
var bmiResult = bmi.toFixed(2);
alert("your weight is" + bmiResult);
if (bmiResult >= 30) {
    alert("obese");
} else if (bmiResult > 25 && bmiResult < 30) {
    alert('overweight');
} else if (bmiResult > 18.5 && bmiResult <= 25) {
    alert('normal');
} else if (bmiResult >= 16 && bmiResult <= 18.5) {
    alert('underweight');
} else if(bmiResult < 16)
{
    alert('very underweight');
}

Answer (score 1):

`else if (bmiResult>=16 || <=18.5)
{     alert('underweight');
}`

error in || <=18.5 did you mean || bmiResult<=18.5

Comment: Thanks for you help!!